# ssh X11 Forwarding will not display Mac OS X Apps on Raspberry PI

Tags: raspberry-pi, openssh, ssh-tunnel, macos-mojave, x11-forwarding

I'm trying to remotely run some apps from my Min Mac running  Mojave  and a raspberry pi 4. When I run ssh -Y from my raspberry pi to the mac I get and error stating **X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0**.  Also the DISPLAY variable is not set on the Mac. When I set the DISPLAY variable to :0.0 the X app (xeyes) displays on the Mac.  When I try setting it to the  the IP of the Raspberry PI (i.e 192.168.1.200:0.0) I get a cannot open display 192.168.1.200:0.0. I modified /etc/sshd_config on the  MAC and the Raspberry to allow X11 forwarding.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.